# How to write WHERE Sql Statement

Tags: python, where-clause

I want to write a WHERE statement, but it shows either error: not such table or nothing [image]

i tried statements in the pic and expected a filtered table

Comment: The `SELECT`-Statement (In(10)) is correct but can not be interpreted by Python. In Python you want to use either the connection.execute as above or pandas.read_sql.

For the line below, from what I see at the top your DB is called `test_db` and not `test`. This might help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the fully qualified name?
Something like "Select * from test_db.CreditCardApps where (rest of statment here)"

If that still doesn't work it might be this command line utility (sqllite3) that may be the problem.

Can I ask, what exactly are you trying to do? There may be an easier way.

Comment: Thank you for help out. I tried "SELECT * FROM test_db.CreditCardApps WHERE DAYS_EMPLOYED >0;", and the output is just printing out this line again. What I want to accomplish here is that, having a pandas data frame, I need to create a database and table stored into that database, and then I need to preform WHERE clause (sth like filter function) and DELETE a row. This is my first time using SQL so not quite sure what is the order and logic

Comment: I'm not familar with sqllite3 but as luca Furrer mentioned if you're calling test instead of test_db (assuming test is not a valid db name) then that is why it's saying it can't find that table.

Comment: In general, my advice would be to avoid calling sqllite3 via command line if possible and focus on calling it via api like you're doing in the top 3 cells of your screenshot. This can often help to avoid issues.
For example c.execute("SELECT * FROM test_db.CreditCardApps WHERE DAYS_EMPLOYED >0;") should work fine and get you what you need.